# Remove parentheses in QString

Tags: qt, replace, qstring, qregexp

I have a `QString` containing "(M001)" and I want to remove the parentheses in text. The result should be "M001". How should I use a `QRegExp` for this?

Comment: Do you want the regular expression to remove **all** parenthesis, or just '(' in the beginning of the string and ')' at the end of string?

Answer (score 3):

If you know your string always has parenthesis, you could just do something like:

```cpp
str = str.mid(1); // Remove first character
str.chop(1);      // Remove last character
```

Otherwise you could also do this instead of using a regular expression:

```cpp
if (str.startsWith('(') && str.endsWith(')')) {
    str = str.mid(1); // Remove first character
    str.chop(1);      // Remove last character
}
```

But if you insist using a `QRegExp`, try this:

```cpp
str.remove(QRegExp("^\\(|\\)$"));
```

or this:

```cpp
str.replace(QRegExp("^\\((.*)\\)$"), "\\1");
```

**EDIT:** If you want to remove ALL parenthesis from the string you can try:

```cpp
str.remove('(').remove(')');
```

or

```cpp
str.remove(QRegExp("[()]"));
```

Comment: I want to use QRegExp. I try it but it doesn't work.

Comment: @user1020141 Corrected an error in my code. Try again.

Answer (score 3):

I see two possible way to do it:

1.Using [`QString::remove()`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qstring.html#remove-2) like this:

```
str.remove("(");
str.remove(")");
```

2.Using [QRegExp](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qregexp.html) class like this:

```
str.remove(QRegExp("[()]"));
```

In both of variants I get "M001" string.
Of course, there are some restrictions: **all** parentheses will be removed.But seems like it's what you want, don't you?

Comment: I don't want to use str.remove(")"); so I asked QRegExp and it works. thanks a lot.